# Asp.net MVC IIS Failed to Execute URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, ckeditor, ckfinder

Hello I'm using CKFinder on CKEditor in an asp.net mvc 5 web application. The problem to be only remote server, no problem in local server. When I select add image on CKEditor and click browse server, my url is `//Scripts/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images&CKEditor=Text&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=tr`. Because of mvc do not allow direct link that is `ckfinder.html` IIS give error. The error is: `System.Web.HttpException: Failed to Execute URL`. How to fix error?

**Description:**

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

> System.Web.HttpException: Failed to Execute URL.

**Source Error:**

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to Execute URL.]
System.Web.Hosting.ISAPIWorkerRequestInProcForIIS6.BeginExecuteUrl(String url, String method, String childHeaders, Boolean sendHeaders, Boolean addUserIndo, IntPtr token, String name, String authType, Byte[] entity, AsyncCallback cb, Object state) +2582829
   System.Web.HttpResponse.BeginExecuteUrlForEntireResponse(String pathOverride, NameValueCollection requestHeaders, AsyncCallback cb, Object state) +412
   System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +192
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error 0x80004005 seems to be permissions problem. Change IIS "pipeline mode" from "classic" to "integrated"

Comment: Well, consists of a vulnerability?